# Grab the name of an element with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a series of Form Elements each with different names, I'll post one as an example. I cannot hard code the name into Jquery because unless I inspect the element, I won't know the name.

With that aside heres the element:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" 
        name="aisis_options[package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master]"
        value="package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master" checked="" /> 
    Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master 
    <a href="#">(Disable)</a>
</label>
```

The catch is to do this:

Grab the name of this element - upon clicking disable - and do two things, one - if the element is checked, which in this case it's not, unchecked it, two pass the name to a php variable, which then can do processing.

How would I do this? Jquery is not my strong area.

Comment: That's not an element...that's many elements. Are these housed inside a form?

Comment: Show some more of you code. Otherwise there is no reference to bind jQuery to

Comment: you probably want to use ajax for this

Comment: "pass the name to a php variable" does this mean you want to send the list of names back to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example without knowing more of your code:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        var iName = this.name;
        $.ajax({
            url: "file.php",
            data: {
                'inputname': iName
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.returned_val);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ6Sd/)**

If you want to reach the input via name directly you need to use double backslasshes to escape the square brackets and reach that input via name. Use:

```
$('input[name=aisis_options\\[package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master\\]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onchange with checkbox 
onchange="f(this);"

in js f() function you can use this.name to get the name, this.value to get value etc and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To check/unckeck, you can use `$element.prop('checked', true/false);` [like this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/FTtn4/1/):

## HTML

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="aisis_options[package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master]" 
    value="...." 
    checked="checked" 
/> Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master 
<a href="#" class="trigger">(Disable)</a>
```

## JS

```
$('.trigger').click (function () {
    closest_checkbox = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]');
    closest_checkbox.prop('checked', !closest_checkbox.prop('checked'));
});
```

## JS part 2: AJAX

You can build an object with all your `name:value` combinations using the [jQuery plugin serializeObject](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject/blob/master/jquery.serializeObject.js), your form submission event handler would be something like:

```
$('form').submit( function (e) {

    // Prevent the form from being sent normally since we want it ajaxified
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Send request to php page
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: $('form').serializeObject()  // <== Magic happens here
    });
});
```

PS. Don't forget to include the serializeObject plugin and give a unique id to the form, `$('#unique_id')` is way better than `$('form')` which will match all the forms in the page.

Comment: This is great but what about grabbing the name of the element and passing it to a php variable? and also there could be 50 checkboxes so how would this script know which checkbox I wanted disabled?

Comment: In php you will have the names as the $_GET or $_POST array indexes, but tell me, do you want to send them to a PHP script with ajax?

Answer (score -1):

To grab the value of name attribute, you can use:

```
$(this).attr('name');
```

Comment: Wyou can't just use $this, I stated there could be many checkboxes.

Comment: If you are binding it onclick, you can. I just gave you the method, how to apply it's up to you.

Comment: The purpose of asking was for an explanation of how to do it.