# In AJAX, do I have to init the class?

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I am trying to do something with out a page refresh (but I think the way I am going about it, will require a page refresh. The ultimate goal is to not have one.

I have two things wrong, one is basic html, the other is not understanding Ajax.

**HTML Issue**

When I click the link beside this element:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="aisis_options[package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master]" 
    value="package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master" checked=""> 
        Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master <a href="#">(Disable)</a>
</label>
```

It then executes this piece of JS:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

Unchecks it, BUT the page refreshes and scrolls to the top. I am assuming there is a js way to stop this or maybe its my stupidity of having "#" in the `<a href="">` part?

**Ajax issue**

I don't understand ajax at all, aside from passing information from the client to the server, so I added the following to the above JS:

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          $.ajax({
              url  : <?php CORETHEME_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_HELPER . 'UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php';?>,
              type : 'GET',
              data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') }       
          });
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

Then wrote the following class:

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper{

    private $_element_name = null;

    public function __construct(){

        if(isset($_GET['element_name'])){
            $this->_element_name = $_GET['element_name'];
            echo $this->_element_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I would like to see the `element_name` echoes when I click the disable link next to the checkbox of the checked object - WITH OUT A PAGE REFRESH if possible.

My issue is, I am not understanding if anything I have done is right, aside from the java script to uncheck the element  [which I got from the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152801/grab-the-name-of-an-element-with-jquery).

please help, The idea is: click the disable, disable the checkbox, echo the element name by passing it to PHP - with out a page refresh if possible.

**Update**

This class is never instantiated. ever. any where. The idea is to do this all with a click, I want to click disable, have it pass the element name to the class and then that class echo the variable all with out a page refresh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML Issue**: As Arun said use  `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default click action.

**AJAX Issue:** What i noticed is that you haven't echoed your url. Change

```
<?php CORETHEME_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_HELPER . 'UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php';?>
```

to

```
<?php echo CORETHEME_ADMIN_TEMPLATE_HELPER . 'UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php';?>
```

Comment: It's a WordPress thing, It will auto Echo for me. That's not my issue, my issue is how is this going to work? How will this, ajax that I created, instantiate the class, pass the variable an then echo the variable to the screen as seen in the class all WITHOUT refresshing the page? you never explained that. Also Please see Update @Ankit

Answer (score 0):

HTML issue. I think the problem is you have not prevented the default action of `a`

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          e.preventDefault();//prevent the default action
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly use Arun's answer, you can just remove the href attribute and it will not go to the top of the page and/or refresh.