# Not sure how to set up Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**Please make sure to read the whole question, there are two questions here.**

Also note: I am NEW to ajax and have no idea what I am doing, I have read Jquerys Ajax docs but I am not sure what I am suppose to do.

## Question 1

I [recently asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162692/in-ajax-do-i-have-to-init-the-class) on how to do this but no one answered the core question about Ajax, they were all so focused on HTML, so I will be more forward this time.

I have the following ajax function for the following element:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="aisis_options[package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master]" 
    value="package_Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master" checked=""> 
        Aisis-Related-Posts-Package-master <a href="#">(Disable)</a>
</label>


(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
          var el = $(this).prev('input[type="checkbox"]');
          if(el.is(':checked')){
               el.prop('checked',false);   
          }
          $.ajax({
              url  : /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Helper/UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php,
              type : 'GET',
              data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') }       
          });
        });
    }); 
 })(jQuery);
```

Now I am not sure if I am suppose yo have `http://localhost/path/to/class`, but it's freaking out stating:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'www' admin.php?page=aisis-core-upload:239`

**So what's the proper way to set this up?**

## Question 2

The above Ajax assumes that their is a form submission, but looking at the "disable" link beside the checkbox it is **NOT** a form submitting element. So **How do I pass the element name to the class WITHOUT submitting a form and still have the class echo out the name?**

This is what my class looks like:

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper{

    private $_element_name = null;

    public function __construct(){

        if(isset($_GET['element_name'])){
            $this->_element_name = $_GET['element_name'];
            echo $this->_element_name;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that I am echoing the element name, Now I am using GET, and in the Ajax stating its a GET request, but it's not - I don't think. I am not submitting any kind of form, I have no intention to submit a form. I just want to **click the link, uncheck the checkbox, pass the name of that element to the class and echo the name out.**

How do I do that?

Comment: You should have the `http://localhost/path/to/class` thing.

Comment: SO is for everybody and their widely varying skill levels - there is a wealth of experience and many people are happy to try and help but a word to the wise: don't duplicate questions.  You can alter your original post and add a bounty if you'd like more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for first question is that `/var/www` is regular expression /var/ with flag www, normal flags are gim. You need to put that path as a string:

```
url  : "/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Helper/UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php",
```

and you should proably put only `"/wordpress/wp-content/"` or `"/wp-content/"` depending where is your root directory.

Second question: you send $_GET using data in ajax, and to get the echo value from php you need to add callback function:

```
      $.ajax({
          url  : "/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/CoreTheme/AdminPanel/Template/Helper/UncheckPackageThemeHelper.php",
          type : 'GET',
          data : { 'element_name' : el.prop('name') },
          success: function(result) {
              alert(result);
          }     
      });
```

Comment: So in my instance GET is what I want? does it instantiate the class automatically? how does it know where I am calling $_GET? I could have a function in there that calls it instead of the constructor....

Comment: @TheWebs I dind't see that, you need to create instance of that class of course `new CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_UncheckPackageThemeHelper();`

Comment: that begs the question of where. where do I create it? Again Im new to all this, Do I create it in the file to which this JS is being called? or do I just instantiate it where ever I like or.... ?? are there rules around that - ajax wise? or is it, "as long as it's instantiated...." @jcubic

Comment: @TheWebs you need to execute it in the file that is executing, and this have nothing to do with ajax. If you want to execute code in constructor you need to create instance of a class.

Comment: Also, there's no form submission, so why am I using GET? - I know POST is for Form Submission and GET is used mostly to get things from the URL, such as params and what not...

Thanks for your help

Comment: @TheWebs you can use both GET and POST in a form.

Comment: How ever a stated numerous times this is not a form submission there is no submission of data if any kind at any time in relation to clicking the disable link. Will my Ajax still work?

Comment: @TheWebs Ajax call is exactly the same thing as form submit, but without page reload. And you do submit the data using ajax. The data is sent.